# Count total value in column MySQL & retrieve value in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP, is there a way to get a total of all values in a column? I tried this query

```
COUNT(player_count) WHERE unique_id = 'test'
```

Basically, if I have a table like this

```
+--------------------------+
| player_count | unique_id |
+--------------+-----------+
| 0            | test      |
+--------------+-----------+
| 5            |           |
+--------------+-----------+
```

I want it the query to return 5.

Also, in a side question, how would you go about doing this in PHP? Normally, to iterate through rows I would do

```
$result = mysql_query("...");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) { /* Code */ }
```

However, I am unsure as how to apply it to a result that should only be a single number.

Would I just do something like

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$total = intval($row["player_count"]);
```

Thanks for your time, I appreciate it

Comment: If you want a total, you need SUM, not COUNT. And you can use mysql_fetch_row to get a single result. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Comment: Oh. How is the query structured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to uso [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum): `SUM(player_count) WHERE unique_id = 'test'`.

And in your "side question" you're right. Just using `mysql_fetch_row` for a unique row will work.

Comment: Thank you! I'll mark this as an answer in 10m with SO lets me

Comment: @user1772510 nice. I'm glad to help.